# Unity specific area touch input

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

i want to make an area in my game where i can get touch inputs from the player.
Now i get touch from all the way of the screen.
**strong text**I want to get from the buttom of the screen or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an invisible UI element or GameObject and on there check if it was clicked or not. You can do this with either https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html or https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html